# Meccano + Raspberry Pi + Arduino

Tags: arduino

I've just started to work with Adruino and Raspberry Pi.

One of the problems I've been wondering about is robot's body. What can I use to build my robot?

I'm reading a book, an old one, about microrobotics. On the final example they are building a robot using Meccano Evolution 1 Kit.

My question is: is there enough room inside a car built with [meccano](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=meccano) to hold an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi?

Sorry, but I'm new on this and I don't know where to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my estimates are right, a Pi and an Arduino should fit, although you might want to get smaller parts to be sure.

I recommend grabbing a Raspberry Pi model A+ and Arduino Pro Mini. The Arduino Pro Mini has the same computational power as an Arduino Uno, but way smaller. The same is true with the A+ and the B+ (assuming your program uses less than 256MB ram).

Comment: ...or a Pi Zero rather than the A+.

Comment: @joan man, you always comment exactly what I was going to comment!

Comment: @PatrickCook sorry ;-)

Comment: @joan or a Zero, but due to availability, I've put A+ on my answer.

Comment: I want to build a robot with a camera that will run an OpenCV program to detect faces. A Raspberry Pi model A+ is enough to run this? I don't know if I need an Arduino but my robot will have two motors. Maybe I need a good book about Raspberry Pi and Arduino before looking for a robot body.

Comment: @VansFannel I recommend crossing your fingers, but a good overclock should make a difference.

Comment: @PandaLion98 Do you recommend me overclock Rapsberry's CPU?

Comment: @VansFannel I don't see anything wrong with it. Fire away!